# How do i modify my query to exclude two specific columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two views in my select statement which shows this information:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| branchID | branchName | staffNo | Full Name | salary | ... |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ....                                                       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM EmployeesAndSalaryByBranch E, CustomersByBranch C
WHERE E.branchID <> 'Headquarters';
```

Now, I wan't to remove the `branchId` and `branchName` columns from the result of the query. One way to do it would be to create a temporary table and drop columns but that is quite **inefficient**.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the opposite, tell which columns to include, i.e. `select staffNo, FullName, ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just exclude the columns from your `select` statement :

This `concatenate` the Firstname and Lastname without a space inbetween:

```
SELECT staffNo, CONCAT(firstName, lastName) AS [Full Name], salary
FROM EmployeesAndSalaryByBranch E, CustomersByBranch C
WHERE E.branchID <> 'Headquarters';
```

This includes the space between Firstname and Lastname :

```
SELECT staffNo, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS [Full Name], salary
FROM EmployeesAndSalaryByBranch E, CustomersByBranch C
WHERE E.branchID <> 'Headquarters';
```

Comment: The 'Full Name' is a `CONCAT(firstName, lastName)` so how do i get that from mysql? Its throwing an error using square brackets